# C++ Linked List Assignment Operator Problem

Tags: c++, class

I am writing an Ordered Linked List class definition (OLList). I have written the assignment operator function, but when I try to test it by chaining assignment operations, the program gets caught in the while loop of the `OLList::copy` function. I know this because I tested using console prints.

```
//OLList.h
struct Node {
  ListItem item;
  Node *next;
};

class OLList {
  public:
  OLList& OLList::operator =(const OLList& rhs)
  {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        destroy();
        copy(rhs);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  void OLList::destroy()
  {
    Node *current_node = this->headM;
    Node *next_node;
    while(current_node->next != nullptr)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        delete(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
    }


    return;
  }

void OLList::copy(const OLList& source)
  {
    Node *new_node, *current_node;
    Node *current_source_node = source.headM;
    this->headM->item = source.headM->item;
    current_node = this->headM;

    while(current_source_node->next != nullptr)
    {
        new_node = new(Node);
        current_node->next = new_node;
        current_node = current_node->next;
        current_source_node = current_source_node->next;
        current_node->item = current_source_node->item;
    }

    return;
  }
}
```

Below is the code used to test the class. I have made sure that the print() function works fine so that's definitely not an issue.

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
    OLList the_list;
    the_list.insert(1);
    the_list.insert(2);

    OLList second_list;
    second_list.insert(3);
    second_list.insert(4);

    OLList third_list;
    third_list.insert(5);
    third_list.insert(6);

    third_list = second_list = the_list;
    third_list.print();
}
```

When it is compiled and run, the program never terminates as it is caught in the loop mentioned above.

Comment: `void OLList::copy(const OLList& source)` -- Why didn't you write a true copy constructor instead of `copy`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `destroy()` method will fail if `headM` is `nullptr`. You should be using `while(current_node != nullptr)` instead of `while(current_node->next != nullptr)`.  But more importantly, it doesn't reset `headM` to `nullptr` after destroying the list.  So after `operator=` calls `destroy()`, `headM` is no longer in a valid state for `copy()` to use.

Your `copy()` method is similarly not checking if either source or target `headM` are `nullptr`. But more importantly, it assumes the target list is empty beforehand, otherwise it leaks memory, if it does not crash outright (per above). And frankly, it simply is not coded correctly in general to copy one list to another.

So, your code is invoking **undefined behavior**, this *anything* could happen.

Like @PaulMcKenzie stated in comments, you really should be using a proper copy constructor instead (and a destructor - and since you are clearly using C++11 or later, a move constructor and move assignment operator, too - see the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).  Your assignment operator can then be implemented using your copy constructor (and likewise for move assignment).

Try something more like this:

```
struct Node {
    ListItem item;
    Node *next = nullptr;

    Node(const ListItem &value) : item(value) {}
};

class OLList {
private:
    Node *headM = nullptr;

public:
    OLList() = default;

    OLList(const OLList &src)
    {
        Node *current_source_node = src.headM;
        Node **current_node = &headM;

        while (current_source_node)
        {
            *current_node = new Node(current_source_node->item);
            current_node = &((*current_node)->next);
            current_source_node = current_source_node->next;
        }

        /* alternatively:
        Node *current_source_node = src.headM;
        while (current_source_node) {
            insert(current_source_node->item);
        }
        */
    }

    OLList(OLList&& src)
    {
        src.swap(*this);
    }

    ~OLList()
    {
        Node *next_node;    

        while (headM)
        {
            next_node = headM->next;
            delete headM;
            headM = next_node;
        }
    }

    void clear() {
        OLList().swap(*this);
    }

    OLList& operator=(const OLList& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            OLList(rhs).swap(*this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    OLList& OLList::operator=(OLList&& rhs)
    {
        OLList(std::move(rhs)).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(OLList &other) {
        std::swap(headM, other.headM);
    }

    void insert(const ListItem &value) {
        ...
    }

    void print() const {
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Well, I assume that would work.. However I'm not doing this for practical purposes; I'm trying to learn it. I still want to know why my code doesn't work, yes I see those problems but they are simple fixes by just adding in an if statement to check for a nullptr Head, and also adding in a 'destroy();' call at the beginning of copy(). What is incorrect about the rest of the process assuming those fixes are made, assuming I still want to stay with this method?

Comment: Also, I did write a copy constructor that calls OLList::copy(). This copy() function is a private helper function used in multiple other functions.

Comment: @Jedediah -- Well there is a flaw in your assignment operator.  You destroyed your data before knowing whether the allocation will work or not.  Using the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) in the assignment operator alleviates this from happening.

Comment: @Jedediah "*What is incorrect about the rest of the process assuming those fixes are made, assuming I still want to stay with this method?*" - well, for one thing, when your `operator=` calls `destroy()`, `headM` is left in an invalid state, and then `copy()` tries to use `headM`, causing **undefined behavior**.